# Hide Blockquotes but replace with Newline

Tags: javascript, css

I have a huge html page with dozens of comments inside blockquotes

Am trying to provide a link to hide all the comments with one click so I used this

var array = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
   array[i].style.display = 'none';
}

This works fine but the problem is the blockquote elements were working also as newline. Now, when I hide the blockquote elements there is no newline.

Is there a way to hide the blockquotes and replace with a newline? This needs to be done without deleting all the text in the blockquotes since it is a toggle show/hide comments.

Comment: example: textt<br> textsdf <blockquote>comment</blockquote> more text dfgd df gdf.

Comment: why dont you given them a class name and hide them?

Comment: need to use diplay:none since some comments are long and display:hide would take hide the blockquote but take up alot of space. thnx

Comment: my point is that why dont you use specific class name? so you can get the tags by class name instead of tag name..

Comment: why would that help? thnx

Answer (score 1):

When you set `display: none`, the element cannot effect the rendering; the page will be shown as if the element were there not at all. So you would need to use some other method of content hiding in order to let the element still cause something, like a line break.

The simplest approach would appear to be to clear the `blockquote` element content and remove its default top and bottom margin, so that it would become an empty block – which consumes no space except in the sense that it implies a line break. To make the operation toggleable, you need to save the real content. Example:

```
var array = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote');
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
   array[i].savedContent = array[i].innerHTML;
   array[i].innerHTML = '';
   array[i].style.margin = 0;
}
```

In the code that restores the comment contents, you would do the opposite operation, restoring `innerHTML` from `savedContent` and setting the top and bottom margins. For consistency, it would be best to set those margins statically to some known values so that you can then restore those same values.

I would expect a property name like `savedContent` to be safe enough (i.e., not clash with any existing property of the element nodes), but to be on the really safe side, it might be better to use a name like `data-content` instead, naturally with bracketed notation instead of dot notation, for example `array[i]['data-content']`.

Comment: trying it out. thanks. get an error when I try to restore the comments that the first array variable is not defined. How do I access the first array variable in the second function?

Comment: You need to make the `array` variable global or to do `var array = document.getElementsByTagName('blockquote')` in the second function too. I assume you tried to use a local variable of a function in an another function, which won’t work here.

Answer (score 0):

```
how about something like this

<br class="b"><blockquote>
commentary
</blockquote><br class="b">

then toggle the display of class b. so 
if blockquote is display:block class b is display:none

and 
if blockquote is display:none class b is display:inline
```